# The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status (drupal-vm)

Tags: 8, composer, virtual-machine

My environment:

- Vagrant 2.2.4
- VirtualBox 6.0.6r130049
- ansible 2.7.10
  config file = None

Mac OS Mojave (10.14.4)

I use [drupal-vm](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm) to build my local development environment.

I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm) and run `vagrant up`. After first time `vagrant up` everything was fine and Drupal was installed correctly. Then I did `vagrant halt`, to stop my VM.

After I do `vagrant up` again I get this error:

```
==> drupalvm: [vagrant-hostsupdater] This operation requires administrative access. You may skip it by manually adding equivalent entries to the hosts file.
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

 setup

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

bash: line 5: setup: command not found
```

What do I have to do and what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to a bug in VirtualBox 6.0.6. I downgraded to 6.0.4 and it now works.

Source: https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/278#issuecomment-486505824

Comment: yes correct. Thats what I just tried and it worked.